# Reusing Objects across multiple domains

Tags: .net, design-patterns, asp.net-web-api

Following Marin Fowler's first law on distributed objects:

[My First Law of Distributed Object Design: Don't distribute your objects](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FirstLaw.html)

This is the typical setup I used when working with Web API solutions:

[image]

The problem is that there is a lot of replication as the entities, pocos and models look almost the same, the exception being the models which might contain serialization attributes. This has always worked fine and libraries such as valueInjecter make the conversion between types trivial, but nevertheless it is complicated to argue of even justify to other people the reasoning behind this. One might argue that the models might be different from a table structure and although that might be true, most of the times the models map directly to the entities/pocos.

That said, would you use a shared library and have a single only?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong with your design:

- What between API and Service is not POCO. It should be Entities.
- What between API and Browser is not Models. It should be DTOs.

You only need to maintain Entities and DTO in your design. The reason for doing so is clear: Domain Model (Entity + Service) is for business aspect. DTO is for communication.